# Minimum length for a String property in DataMapper

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

Im using DataMapper in my Sinatra application.I defined a property called 'to' whose minimum length i want to be 10

```
property :to,String,:required => true,:min => 10
```

This causes my application to crash with the error

> assert_valid_options': options :min are unknown (ArgumentError)

Am i specifying the min length in the right way ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
validates_length_of :to, :min => 10
```

If you know the maximum length of your string, you can do

```
property :to,String,:required => true,:min => 10 ,:length => 10..20  #length must be between 10 to 20 char
```